# Order of execution of lambdas from multiple parallel_for_each calls

Tags: c++-amp

Let's say I have C++ AMP code with two `parallel_for_each` calls in a row. Will all the lambdas from the first call complete before lambdas from the second call begin?

In general, is there any guarantee about the order of execution of lambdas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, the lambda typically will not complete.

Longer answer: The parallel_for_each queues the request to the GPU, and then your CPU thread continues to the second parallel_for_each and queues that, and then your CPU thread continues to execute other CPU code. In the meantime, in a non-deterministic manner, the computations are going to execute on the accelerators that you queued them on (if on the default accelerator, the first computation will execute and then the second computation will execute). In between the executions of the computations, or even after both computations, if at any point you try to access the results of any of the computations then the CPU thread will block while waiting for the results to be copied back (and if necessary wait for the execution to complete). One way you can do that is by calling synchronize on one of the output array_view objects you captured in the lambda passed to the p_f_e.

If you want to just wait for the computation to complete (without triggering back a copy), call wait on the accelerator_view.

BTW, you do not have to manage data dependencies between different parallel_for_each invocations. The underlying runtime does that for you. So it is fine to use the same array_View in consequitive parallel_for_each calls and the data will be ready for the second one without having to come back to the host CPU.

If this is still not clear to you, please share repro code so we can be more concrete.

To learn more about the C++ AMP, please start here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/09/13/c-amp-in-a-nutshell.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Daniel. Your "BTW" paragraph is really what I was looking for. I just didn't ask clearly enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can answer this yourself with the concurrency visualizer. If you are using a queued view, it's possible both pfes will consider themselves to be done (they don't block, they return) while the code has not yet run on the GPU. If you want to be sure that the first one has finished, use its results somehow (eg copy the array back to the CPU or use the array_view) which will make the code start to run on the accelerator.

If you don't touch / ask for the results from the first pfe until after you've sent off the second pfe, why would you want a guarantee about running order? If you do touch or ask for the results, that's what controls the way things execute.

Comment: Running order would matter if both pfes modified the same array_view. Maybe I should modify my question with that stipulation. Does the second pfe (which references the same array_view) count as "using" the results?